# How to select from table A only where a relationship between the table A row and a specific row in B exists?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, rdbms

lets say I have two MySQL tables, table A and table B. Each table has a primary key called id and a name column. I also have a third table, table C, that contains relationships between table A and table B. Each row contains two foreign keys called a_id and b_id, which, as you might expect, correspond to ids in tables A and B.

What I want to do is select a random set of 10 table A rows, but only select rows that have a relationship with specific entries in table B. I don't know which entries I'm looking for ahead of time, and I will start with their names. The names will be provided via query parameters.

I understand I should probably start with this:

```
SELECT * FROM `A`
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

But I don't know how to structure the where clause.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `A` a
INNER JOIN `C` c ON
    a.ID = c.a_id AND
    c.b_id in (1,2,3,4) -- your entries here

-- order and limit as you wish
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: 1. I have table B's ids in table C, but I'm starting with table B's names not ids. I was going to do a separate query where I pull the corresponding table B ids, but I just want to make sure there isnt a better way to do this in 1 query.

Comment: 2. Is there a way to make the number of B ids arbitrary? In your example, you take 4 ids, but when if I want to be able to take 2 or 7? My plan was to just template out the query in js before running it, but I wanted to make sure there wasnt a way to do it in pure SQL first.

Comment: 1.`SELECT *
FROM A a
INNER JOIN C c ON
    a.ID = c.a_id AND
INNER JOIN B b ON c.b_id = b.id
WHERE B.name IN ('x', 'x', 'x', 'x')

-- order and limit as you wish
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 10`


About performance I can't say wich is better. You have to test the separated query and this one with all together.

Comment: 2. in pure SQL I don't think it is possible. Usually ORMs can handle this when they receive an array or list as parameter inside an IN clause. With pure SQL you could insert all your B names in a temporary table and then your select would be something like this: 
`SELECT * FROM A a INNER JOIN C c ON     a.ID = c.a_id AND INNER JOIN B b ON c.b_id = b.id INNER JOIN TempTable t ON T.b_name = b.name -- order and limit as you wish ORDER BY RAND()  LIMIT 10`. It's more complex, but is an alternative.

Comment: Thank you so much! You rock! For the first one, we don't need the AND between the joins, but after I removed that it worked perfectly. For the second, I think I'm going to go the route of generating my SQL in a js script.